# send json data from php

Tags: php, json

I am totally new to Php and i am trying to send json data from php to android.I have the following code in php to read value from data base:

```
<?php
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");

if(! $con)
{
        die('Connection Failed'.mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("registration",$con);
$name="Adam";//$_POST["name"];
$password="charles";//$_POST["password"];
$sql="SELECT * FROM users WHERE name='$name'and password='$password'"; 

$result=mysql_query($sql, $con);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))     
{
    $details= array(
        'name' => $row['name'],
        'password' => $row['password'],

    );
    array_push($json, $bus);
}

$jsonstring = json_encode($json);
echo $jsonstring;
mysql_close();
?>
```

I am expecting the output to be something like this:

```
[{"name":"Adam","age":"25","surname":"charles"}]
```

If i am not wrong the JSON data.
But this gives me error :

```
mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, resource given in...
```

and also

```
Undefined variable: json in...
```

can somebody pleease tell me what might be the possible error

Comment: 1. You are using `mysql_*`and `mysqli_*` (pick one, and please pick mysqli :) ). 2. `$json` is not defined anywhere (you should define it above with `$json = array();`). 3. `$bus` is not defined anywhere - did you mean `$details`? 4. Please make yourself familiar with SQL Injection (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try as this

```
$result=mysql_query($sql, $con);
$json = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))     
 {
    $json[]= array(
       'name' => $row['name'],
     'password' => $row['password']
    );
}

$jsonstring = json_encode($json);
 echo $jsonstring;
```

And mysql is deprecated, when you can use mysqli or PDO

Answer (score 8):

In addition to the changes suggested by sam and pitchinnate, also consider adding php header to set the content type to json

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
```

That is if you are using android to request the json information remotely

Answer (score 1):

You are using `mysql_query` with `mysqli_fetch_array`. You need to use `mysql_fetch_array`.

However mysql_* functions shouldn't be used anymore.

Also another error:

```
array_push($json, $bus); // i believe $bus should be replaced with $details
```

Comment: ,Can u please tell me what is wrong in the above

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check the content of you variable $result (var_dump()); In fact, if result is not defined, your program will not enter the loop and $json won't be defined.

Answer (score 0):

Undefined variable: json
is caused because you are trying to do array_push($json, $bus)  but $json doesnt exist.

you should declare it first

```
$json = Array();
```

The mysql error is most likely caused because you are mixing mysql and mysqli modules.

Use mysqli only.

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("registration",$con);
...
$result=mysql_query($sql, $con);
```

Also it is generally a bad idea to store passwords in plain text. Consider using a hash function at least.