# Failing to return data from AJAX, no promises are triggered

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, post

I'm attempting to POST some data to a PHP file using the jQuery $.ajax function, and return a response. I've done similar things in the past, so I'm not sure where I'm slipping up.

I've attached DONE, FAIL, THEN, and ALWAYS promises to the $.ajax function, each with alerts in them, and no alerts are being fired. Here is the relevant JavaScript.

```
$.ajax({
        url: "processingForm.php",
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
        data: { theFullData: JSON.stringify(postData) },
    success: function (obj, textstatus) {
        alert("Woo");
    },
    error: function (err) {
        alert("Error");
    }
    })
   .done(function (res) {
       alert(res);
   })
   .fail(function (res) {
       alert("fail");
   })
   .then(function (res) {
        alert("then");
   })
   .always(function () {
        alert("complete");
   });
```

In my PHP file, the JSON data is parsed and eventually a string is inserted into the database. The string is written to the database properly about 75% of the time. I've never seen anything written to the LOG table, so maybe that is an issue for another post.

```
    $outp = array();
        $sql = (string)('INSERT INTO PBP_O (POST_DATA) values ("' . $str . '")');
        mysqli_query($conn, $sql);


        //ERROR Logging
        $err = mysqli_error($conn);

$sql = (string)('INSERT INTO LOG (ERROR) values ("Hi")');
mysqli_query($conn, $sql);


        if($err != ""){
            mysqli_close($conn);

            echo "Sorry";
        }
        else{

$sql = (string)('INSERT INTO LOG (ERROR) values ("Way down here")');
mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

            $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() LID");

            if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                    $outp["LID"] = $row["LID"];
                }
            } else {
                echo "Sorry";
            }
        }

$sql = (string)('INSERT INTO LOG (ERROR) values ("'.$outp["LID"].'")');
mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

        mysqli_close($conn);
        echo json_encode($outp);
```

If anyone has an idea of what I'm doing wrong, I'd be extremely grateful. Please let me know if there are any other parts of the code that would be helpful to see. I've verified that the JSON being sent is valid already.

**EDIT**
Could $.post() potentially do anything for me that my current AJAX wouldn't? I don't see why it would, but then again I don't see the bug in my code either.

**EDIT 2**

I've updated my PHP code to what it is now (the edited portions are farthest to the left). I've also added the SUCCESS and ERROR callbacks to the AJAX. Basically I'm just using my LOG table to make sure that I'm where I should be. Every single insert in that PHP code inserts successfully, including the data that I'm echoing to be caught by the AJAX. Which I would normally take to mean that it is running to the end.

*Side note*, I'm using Visual Studio. When I was using IE for debugging, the alerts inside all of the AJAX callbacks would not fire. I switched to Chrome, and they were able to be caught and did fire.

In the Chrome > Network Tool, there were two entries. First, a call to *processing.php*, which was red. There was a second call to *index.html?yearsGroup1=2016&yearsGroup2=2016...*, followed by all of the variables on the page in the style of a GET request [which I now realize is just the page reloading itself after SUBMIT].

Finally, when I inspected *err* in the AJAX -> ERROR callback, I saw:

```
Object {readyState: 0, responseJSON: undefined, status: 0, statusText: "error"}
```

I'm not too sure where to go from here.

Comment: Maybe you just need `success: function (data) {
           alert('Success' +data);
       }`

Comment: @FreezY Sorry, no luck with that. I appreciate the input though.

Comment: You're going to have to help me out here. What specifically isn't working as you expect?

Comment: try to set error display on in php and edit your post with the error

Comment: Can you please open the console and see if anything is being reported either in the error console or in networking? Your Ajax call should at least fire a network request to processingForm.php. from there you should be able to determine whether it's timing out, or 404ing or not firing at all (for some reason).

Comment: Try adding an `error: function(err){ alert(err) }`

Comment: @EatPeanutButter I was expecting to see some of the alerts fire. More detail in Edit 2.

Comment: @NishanthMatha No errors (that I can detect) are occurring in the PHP. More detail in Edit 2.

Comment: @LiamEgan I've attempted to do so. More detail in Edit 2.

**Thank you all for taking the time to try to help me**

Comment: The fact that the call to processing.php is red tells me that it's erroring -- 400, 404, or 500 most likely. Can you inspect the call and tell me what the error code is and whether there's a response document that may shed light on the issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [send json data from php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15281707/send-json-data-from-php)

Answer (score 0):

So for whatever reason, when I transferred my code over to a different folder, a non-breaking warning started to appear:

**Warning**: Unknown Property access is not allowed yet in **Unknown** on line **0**

At which point I put my head through my  monitor. ***PSA***: Don't be an idiot like me, always check your PHP 15 extra times for errors.

I apologize to everyone who commented on this for wasting your time on my general incompetence. Thank you all again for your help.